# What is causing PHP Intelephense v1.7.1 to display Undefined function?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, wordpress-theming

I just installed PHP Intelephense v1.7.1 vscode extension to help with theme development. I am now getting the following errors being displayed. How can I fix this error?

[image: Error being displayed in the code]

Answer (score 2):

there are a few extensions that help with wordpress development. e.g. 'Wordpress Hooks Intellisense' helps vscode recognize wordpress specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VS Code Workspace settings or VS Code Folder settings and look for the **Intelephense › Environment: Include Paths** setting.

Here click Add Item and enter the path of a Wordpress installation main index.php file like :

```
"/your/path/to/wordpress/admin/index.php"
```

or

```
"/your/path/to/wordpress/index.php"
```

This will prevent displaying Wordpress functions and constants errors.